# What is Foo(int* ptr): ptr_{ptr}{}?

Tags: c++

I saw this code in the book "C++ High Performance" by Bjorn Andrist and Viktor Sehr.
The code example is actually used to show the point that "Compiles despite function being declared `const`!", and I am aware of this. However, I have not seen `int* ptr_{};` and `Foo(int* ptr):ptr_{ptr}{}` before this point. What are these two pieces of code doing, especifically `Foo(int* ptr):ptr_{ptr}{}`?
The entire code snippet used as an example was this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int* ptr):ptr_{ptr}{}
    auto set_ptr_val(int v) const {
        *ptr_ = v; // Compiles despite function being declared const!
    }

private:
    int* ptr_{};
};

int main(){
    auto i = 0;
    const auto foo = Foo{&i};
    foo.set_ptr_val(42);
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 You missed the first line which was hidden in a markdown error by OP. The second most efficient way of hiding important information in a StackOverflow post.

Comment: Better get your formatting right, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help , or you will have more users misreading your posts.

Comment: The example code looks weird to me! Why we see a pointer default initialization if we have a constructor which initializes the ptr? Why we have auto for a function that returns nothing? And what is the sense of the code at all? To access a constant pointer in a constant function did not mean we access a pointer to a constant value. Why such an obscure example with a class/object only to show that we have const pointers vs pointers to const?

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, I did try to do it correctly and I didn't realize there were that many formatting issues. Also yes, I was inquiring about the class constructor that also makes use of member initializer lists. As for the weird code, I don't know much about it as it came from a book and did not have much context. I think it mainly used to emphasize a point.

Comment: What I want to say: If the rest of the book uses also obscure examples for simple things, it will not really be a good book for my point of view! The "always auto" usage and the multiple indirection's only to show that a const pointer points to a non const variable is not really helpful I believe. "Compiles despite function being declared const" is fully pointing to the wrong direction. There is nothing modified inside the object so there is nothing "despite...". More general: If a const function can not do anything, it will never be useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
Foo(int* ptr) : ptr_{ptr}{}
```

- Declares and defines a constructor for the class `Foo`,
- which takes in input a `int *` (pointer to `int`),
- and initializes the member variable `ptr_` via the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor);
- it does nothing more, so the body is emtpy, `{}`.

---

```cpp
int* ptr_{};
```

uses one possible syntax of [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) to [zero initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) `ptr_`; since it of type `int*`, it will be inialized with `nullptr`, so that's equivalent to `int* ptr_{nullptr};`.

---

As regards the point they're making, I think they are overstressing a normal observation thus making it look like a special rule:

- the class has a member named `ptr_` which is a `int*`, i.e. a pointer to `int`;
- the member function `set_ptr_val` is `const`, so it makes the promise that it won't change `ptr_` or any other (non-`mutable`) member;
- indeed `set_ptr_val`'s body ***doesn't*** modify `ptr_`; what it modifies is the pointed-to `int`. But that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the easy one: `int* ptr_{};`. This just defines a member variable named `ptr_` that is a pointer to an `int`. The `{}` just initializes it to null.

Next up is `Foo(int* ptr):ptr_{ptr}{}`. If we format this differently it becomes much clearer what is going on:

```
Foo(int* ptr)
: ptr_{ptr}
{
}
```

This is a constructor, as evidenced by the use of the class name `Foo`. It takes a single argument (which is what enables the use of `Foo{&i}` inside of `main()`). On from there, the colon (`:`) begins an *member initializer list*, which is where member variables can be initialized. In general this can be a comma-separated list of *member initializers*. The code `ptr_{ptr}` is one such member initializer, and it initializes the member variable `ptr_` to have the same value as the argument `ptr`. I.e., `ptr_` will point to the same `int` as `ptr`. Finally we have the constructor body, which in this case is empty so is composed of nothing but braces.

Comment: @Yunnosch, actually the OP wrote _I have not seen `int* ptr_{};` and `Foo(int* ptr):ptr_{ptr}{}` before this point. What are these two pieces of code doing?_, so they _are_ asking about that too.

Comment: True, admittedly (and I did not see it). But I think being extra clear about which line is explained where does not hurt. But you are right, not strictly needed....